# mvc3 partialview doesn't load query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I have Partial View that is updated with AJAX. The problem is that Partial View needs to take two parameters and one isn't in query string.

this is controller

```
public ActionResult _Unutrasnjost(string verzijaIme,int bojeId=0)
{
    return PartialView(repositoryU.BojeUnutrasnjostVezano.Where(v =>v.VerzijaIme==verzijaIme&&v.BojeId == bojeId).ToList());
}
```

string verzijaIme is in query string but when the partialview is loaded it tells me that is undefined

int bojeId isnt in query string but when user clicks on button its send by AJAX.

I dont understand why everything is working if I put only one parameter (string or int) and if I put two parameters verzijaIme is undefined?

Its also working if I remove =0 from int bojeId and put that parameter in query string but I cant accept that kind of solution

Any suggestion?

Ajax code

```
function unutrasnjostData(id) {
        var urlclear = '@Url.Action("_Unutrasnjost", "Configurator")' + "?bojeId=" + id;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlclear,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#meniDesnoIzmjeneUnutrasnjost').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code that is invoking this controller action with AJAX?

Comment: You doesn't seem to be sending the `verzijaIme` parameter in your AJAX request. It is nowhere to be seen in the query string so it is normal that it will be null inside your controller action.

Comment: this is a link when i load partialview
..Configurator/Izvana?verzijaId=14&ModeliId=1&VerzijaIme=Easy%203V%2023Q
and verzija ime exsit...thats why im confused

Comment: i think the problem is that i cant call one parametar from link and other from AJAX...but im not sure

Comment: How are you building this link? The code you have shown doesn't seem tpo be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not passing `verzijaIme` to partial view at all. You need to extend your `unutrasnjostData` function:

```
function unutrasnjostData(id, verzijaIme) {
        var urlclear = '@Url.Action("_Unutrasnjost", "Configurator")' + "?bojeId=" + id + "&verzijaIme=" + verzijaIme;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlclear,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#meniDesnoIzmjeneUnutrasnjost').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Or, even better, send it in post:

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: { bojeId: id, verzijaIme: verzijaIme },
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlclear,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#meniDesnoIzmjeneUnutrasnjost').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Don't confuse the query string from the request to the page with the query string from the AJAX call. Those are two separate requests.

Comment: no that is not a problem. AJAX is working. Problem acures when the page is first loaded and I request query string verzijaIme in my partial view. it say that is undefind and it cant be becouse its in query string....

Comment: ok i need to call one parameter from link: Request.QueryString[] etc. and one from AJAX bojeId in same controler. is that possible?

Comment: in other words when i load the page verzijaIme=easy3cv5 and bojeId=0 and afetr that i only change bojeId with AJAX and verzijaIme stay the same. problem is when the page is load it say that Request.QueryString["verzijaIme"] is undifind and i have it in my link